# Node.js Oracle ORM

Tags: oracle, node.js, orm

I'm pretty new to Node.js, I have to do an application that has to use an Oracle database.
I found this ORM to connect to an Oracle database https://github.com/nearinfinity/node-persist but the documentation is very poor for Oracle.
Does someone know if there is a better solution or have some example to manage the module with Oracle?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is [sworm](https://github.com/featurist/sworm), a light-touch ORM that we've used pretty extensively with Oracle, but also supports SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres and SQLite3.

Answer (score 3):

Use TypeORM for Oracle. Best fit for Typescript based applications but also can be used with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find for nodejs the ORM's that are best supported are for open source databases such as mongodb (mongoose) and mysql (sequelize and bookshelf(haven't used that))

Mongoose and MongoDB is what I use with nodejs and that's my recommendation.

I do work alot with Oracle and companies that use Oracle tend to use ADF (Java), APEX (PL/SQL) plus other Oracle specific tools (Report Writer, Oracle Forms)

Answer (score 0):

[Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) is a modern TypeScript and Node.js ORM for **Oracle**, Postgres, MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite and SQL Server, and more. Featuring solid transaction support, relations, eager and lazy loading, read replication and more.